# Git: How to clone repos with cross-referencing submodules recursively?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I'm working on a project with two of my git repos cross-referencing their submoudles.

But when I clone one branch of one cross-submoduling repo recursively, another repo's branch as a submodule in the cloned repo will be empty.

For example, two repos: `REPO1` with its two branches `1A` and `1B`, and `REPO2` with its two branches `2A` and `2B`.

`REPO1/1A`(repo/branch) has `REPO2/2A` as a submodule , and `REPO2/2B` has `REPO1/1B` as a submodule.

When I `git clone --recursive -b 1A` for `REPO1`, `REPO2/2A` will only have an empty top folder in the cloned `REPO1/1A`.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This shall do:

- clone the main repo
- init and update submodule

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

- switch branch

```
git checkout 1A
```

- update submodule
  (updates the submodules to the latest commit of their respective branches.)

```
git submodule update --recursive --remote
```